# Integrity constraint violation Magneto v1.9 Adding REST role to user

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

The following occurs when I try to add a REST role to a user under Permission > Users. Tried this with all users created and also disabled caching but still same problem occurs.

Any solution will be helpful.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mag_db`.`api2_acl_user`, CONSTRAINT `FK_API2_ACL_USER_ADMIN_ID_ADMIN_USER_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admin_user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `api2_acl_user` (`admin_id`, `role_id`) VALUES (?, ?)

Trace:
#0 /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ap...', Array)
#4 /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ap...', Array)
#5 /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ap...', Array)
#6 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource/Acl/Global/Role.php(74): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('api2_acl_user', Array)
#7 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Observer.php(56): Mage_Api2_Model_Resource_Acl_Global_Role->saveAdminToRoleRelation('4', '4')
#8 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Api2_Model_Observer->saveAdminToRoleRelation(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#9 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Api2_Model_Observer), 'saveAdminToRole...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('admin_user_save...', Array)
#11 /home/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_user_save...', Array)
#12 /home/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#13 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php(141): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#14 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController->saveAction()
#15 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#16 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the table from the server and re-imported a backup version of the table. 
Foreign Key constraint is most likely to be broken/corrupted, thus requiring the replacement.

There is a duplicate of ID which caused the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

your database integrity is messed up. This could happen if someone created or deleted a user or gained permissions straight inside db with foreign key check turned off.

Comment: try to use magento database repair tool. http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html